# Imported Range Query Results in Google Sheets are not being formatted (i.e. number format is still in text format)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to consolidate different data sources using importrange, and I need the formatting of number values to be, of course, numbers. Initially the imported date will be in text value so I add the formatting condition using Query. It's weird because only a couple of columns are converted to number format and the rest are in text. I need to have them in number so I can pivot in another sheet and create a dashboard and at the same time have a whole view of the consolidated data.

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE($C$1,"A2:AN");IMPORTRANGE($C$3,"A2:AN"),"select * format Col17 '##.00',Col18 '##.00',Col19 '##.00',Col20 '##.00',Col21 '##.00',Col22 '##.00',Col23 '##.00'"`

[image: OUTPUT]

Really sorry if this a stupid question. Im really new to this. Thanks in advance tho!

Comment: Can you share an extract of $C$1 and $C$3 spreadsheets so that we could investigate?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Hi, team. so I found out why some columns are not converting into numbers, because some of the cells in the column contain a "-" instead of a zero. I've changed all of these dashes into zeros but not all of the columns have converted into number. I'll post the requested info in the post itself

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IFERROR(
--{IMPORTRANGE($C$1,"A2:AN");IMPORTRANGE($C$3,"A2:AN")},
  {IMPORTRANGE($C$1,"A2:AN");IMPORTRANGE($C$3,"A2:AN")}
  )
)
```